# Create, search, insert and delete contacts in Adress Book

Tags: java

I am new to java and have been in touch since last two weeks. How could I create new contact, search and delete.

### Edit

Used suggestion from answers and learned some new stuff. I am now able to store, search, delete any contact using Database through using queries. I needed database connection.

### Driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        AddressBook adbook = new AddressBook();

        System.out.print("Type your first name: ");
        adbook.fname = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type middle name: ");
        adbook.mname = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type last name: ");
        adbook.lname = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type National Identity Card Number: ");
        adbook.nic = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type Home Adress: ");
        adbook.homead = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type Home Phone Number: ");
        adbook.homeph = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type Business Address: ");
        adbook.busadd = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type Business Phone: ");
        adbook.busph = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type Cell Number: ");
        adbook.cellnum = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Type Fax Number: ");
        adbook.faxnum = in.nextLine();

        adbook.showDetails();
    }
}
```

### Address Book Class

```
public class AddressBook {

    String fname;
    String mname;
    String lname;
    String nic;
    String homead;
    String homeph;
    String busadd;
    String busph;
    String faxnum;
    String cellnum;

    public AddressBook(String f_name, String m_name, String l_name,
        String n_ic, String home_ad, String home_ph,
        String bus_ad, String bus_ph, String fax_num, String cell_num) {
        fname = f_name;
        mname = m_name;
        lname = l_name;
        nic = n_ic;
        homeph = home_ph;
        homead = home_ad;
        busadd = bus_ad;
        busph = bus_ph;
        faxnum = fax_num;
        cellnum = cell_num;
    }

    AddressBook() {
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public String getNic() {
        return nic;
    }

    public String getHomead() {
        return homead;
    }

    public String getHomeph() {
        return homeph;
    }

    public String getBusad() {
        return busadd;
    }

    public String getBusph() {
        return busph;
    }

    public String getCellnum() {
        return cellnum;
    }

    public String getFaxnum() {
        return faxnum;
    }

    public void showDetails() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your Address Book Goes Here");
        System.out.println("Your Full Name is: " + fname + " " + mname + " " + lname);
        System.out.println("Natinal Identity Card Number: " + nic);
        System.out.println("Home Address: " + homead);
        System.out.println("Phone Number: " + homeph);
        System.out.println("Business Adress: " + busadd);
        System.out.println("Business Number: " + busph);
        System.out.println("Cell Number: " + cellnum);
        System.out.println("Fax Number: " + faxnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are just inputing data what you wanted to do ?save them in DB show in UI or anything else?

Comment: Saving them in DB and needed UI too!

Comment: for that you need to learn JDBC,in that you will find how to connect to DB and execute statements ....http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call its constructor, a new contact is created.

```
    AddressBook b1=new AddressBook(parameters...);
    AddressBook b2=new AddressBook(parameters...);
    .
    .
```

That means your data will be saved temporarily in respective objects.
So it would be much better to have an UI and a file or database to permanently store the data. Deletion will be easy in DB.

Comment: Which DB would you like to suggest! What kind of DB will be better for begginers to get started with like me?

Comment: You can either go for file handling or you can also learn to use 'sql' it is easy to use. Initially you should go for file handling but for the bigger projects database systems like 'sql' or 'MS-Excel' will be a better option for you.

Comment: I have started learning the file handling. Thanks for your help.